# Group By and contact rows except the default value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ MSG_ID ║ RANDOM_ID ║  MSG  ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║        22 ║ apple ║
║      2 ║        22 ║ bag   ║
║      3 ║         0 ║ cat   ║
║      4 ║         0 ║ dog   ║
║      5 ║         0 ║ egg   ║
║      6 ║        21 ║ fish  ║
║      7 ║        21 ║ hen   ║
║      8 ║        20 ║ glass ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

Result Required :

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ RANDOM_ID ║    MSG    ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╣
║        22 ║ apple bag ║
║         0 ║ cat       ║
║         0 ║ dog       ║
║         0 ║ egg       ║
║        21 ║ fish hen  ║
║        20 ║ glass     ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

I want it to be grouped by random_id but for random_Id=0 I don't want it to be grouped.
Any suggestion will be apprecitiated.

```
Select  random_id as a, 
        (
            Select group_concat( message ORDER BY random_id ASC SEPARATOR ' ')
            from messagemaster 
            where  flag = 0  AND random_id=a
            group by random_id 
            order by random_id 
        ) as msg
from    messagemaster
where   flag = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  Random_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(msg SEPARATOR ' ') Msg
FROM    TableName
WHERE   Random_ID <> 0
GROUP   BY Random_ID
UNION
SELECT  Random_ID, Msg
FROM    TableName
WHERE   Random_ID = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc10a/8)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*preserving order*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc10a/9)